# How can I zoom in a ggmap plot that uses shapefiles?

Tags: r, zooming, shapefile, ggmap

I’m trying to plot a map of Europe with every country filled in a colour according to a certain numeric value – I thought this should be no problem with shapefiles (that I got here http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) and ggmap. However it only works for a very large map but I am not able to properly zoom in.

I tried to do so by setting `xlim()` and `ylim()`, but since thereby I was cutting off shapes at the edges, R connected points that were not supposed to be connected. For ggplot I could solve this issue by using `coord_fixed(xlim,  ylim)` instead, but when applying the same to my ggmap-plot the country shapes and the map would not fit onto each other anymore.

[ggmap with wrong shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZl0X.png)

Here is my code that I used for the plot:

```
my.map <- get_map(location = "europe", source = "google", maptype = "satellite", zoom = 3)

ggmap(my.map) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = eu$value, size = .2, color = 'green', data = eu, alpha = 0.5) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 35),  ylim = c(35, 65), ratio = 1.6)
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem?
(I know it works with ggplot but I'd really like to use ggmap.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coord_map()` instead of `coord_fixed()`:

```
my.map <- get_map(location = "europe", source = "google", maptype = "satellite", zoom = 3)
ggmap(my.map)+
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill='white', size=.2, color='green', data=eu, alpha=0.5)+
  coord_map(xlim=c(0, 35), ylim=c(35, 65))
```

[image: resulting map]